# handling multiple AWS ECS fargate tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-elb

So I have been able to follow a guide on how to set up a single task and have the relevant port be listened to using load balancer. I am struggling to wrap my head around where i have multiple tasks. Do i need multiple lb one for each task and allocate different ports and have each one listen to the other that i want to run in sequence?

Tried setting up a single load balancer to utilise for multiple tasks but it caused things to break. Also tried setting multiple lb one for each but things stopped after the first task and unable to find answers online which most probably means im not asking the right questions

Answer (score 1):

You can update the ALB rules to use Path based routing or host based routing. There are multiple options. Please check this

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-advanced-request-routing-for-aws-application-load-balancers/